# In pytest print text to testrail comment

Tags: python, pytest, testrail

I am using pytest-testrail plugin to upload test result to testrail. I'd like to post the output from my test program (usually using a print command) to testrail also. How can we do this? I tried something like pytest -rA or -s etc. without success.

for example, one of my test cases:

```
@pytestrail.case('C18346')
@pytest.mark.hw
@pytest.mark.debug
def test_cputemp():
    cmd = "cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/temp*_input"
    r = ssh_client.execute(cmd)
    print()
    print(r['out'])
    print("Please check the temperatures are normal")
    assert r['retval'] == 0
```

How to post printed content to testrail?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: pytest -k debug --testrail --tr-run-id=355 -s --ip 10.1.0.237 -v